# Failable initializer with Result type?

Tags: swift, initializer, resulttype, failable

I have a struct `MyStruct`. It can be initialized from a String, but there are many ways for the String to be invalid. Rather than simply creating a failable initializer `init?(string: String)` which returns the same `nil` in all of the failure cases, I would like to have an initializer that returns a Result type of `Result<MyStruct, Error>` so that the calling method can know which failure case occurred and report an informative error.

I can write a method `static func makeNew(string: String) -> Result<Self, Error>`. That way instead of calling

```
guard let new = MyStruct(string: someString) else {
   print("\(someString) was invalid somehow.")
}
print("Object created.)
```

I could call `makeNew` like this:

```
switch MyStruct.makeNew(string: someString) {
case .success(let new):
   print("Object created")
case .failure(let error):
   switch error {
      // handle each specific error appropriately
   }
}
```

Is this the only way, or does Swift give us an actual initializer to do this?

Comment: Seems like this is maybe a better fit for an `init` that `throws`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `throw` from your initializer instead:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    struct ValidationError: Error {} // Example error

    init(_ string: String) throws {
        guard isValid() else { throw ValidationError() }
        ...
    }
}

do {
    let new = try MyStruct("some string")
    print("Object created: \(new)")
} catch let e as MyStruct.ValidationError {
    // handle each specific error appropriately
} catch {
    print("Other unexpected error")
}
```

Functions that return `T` (or initializers for `T`) marked `throws` are roughly isomorphic to ones that return `Result<T, any Error>`.